# Packaging-up Browser/Server CommonJS modules with dependancies

Tags: javascript, node.js, module, browserify, commonjs

Lets say I'm writing a module in JavaScript which can be used on both the browser and the server (with Node). Lets call it **Module**. And lets say that that **Module** would benefit from methods in another module called **Dependancy**. Both of these modules have been written to be used by both the browser and the server, à la CommonJS style:

***module.js***

```
if (typeof module !== 'undefined' && module.exports)
  module.exports = Module; /* server */
else
  this.Module = Module; /* browser */
```

***dependancy.js***

```
if (typeof module !== 'undefined' && module.exports)
  module.exports = Dependancy; /* server */
else
  this.Dependancy = Dependancy; /* browser */
```

Obviously, **Dependancy** can be used straight-out-of-the-box in a browser. But if **Module** contains a `var dependancy = require('dependency');` directive in it, it becomes more of a hassle to 'maintain' the module.

I know that I could perform a global check for **Dependancy** within **Module**, like this:

```
var dependancy = this.Dependancy || require('dependancy');
```

But that means my **Module** has two added requirements for browser installation:

- the user must include the **dependency.js** file as a `<script>` in their document
- and the user must make sure this script is loaded before **module.js**

Adding those two requirements throws the idea of an easy-going modular framework like CommonJS.

The other option for me is that I include a second, compiled script in my **Module** package with the `dependency.js` bundled using [browserify](http://browserify.org/). I then instruct users who are using the script in the browser to include this script, while server-side users use the un-bundled entry script outlined in the `package.json`. This is preferable to the first way, but it requires a pre-compilation process which I would have to run every time I changed the library (for example, before uploading to GitHub).

Is there any other way of doing this that I haven't thought of?

Comment: That is a terrible idea, server and browser should not share the same library for security reasons, that is why we need both in the first place. imagine, one of your dependencies exposes your users email or passwords or something like that. It would be disastrous.

Comment: @Val There are many common libraries that can be used both server and browser side that do not touch on security. Case in point, the [async](https://github.com/caolan/async) library. Furthermore, in this case, both **Module** and **Dependency** are written by myself.

Answer (score 4):

The two answers currently given are both very useful, and have helped me to arrive at my current solution. But, as per my comments, they don't quite satisfy my particular requirements of both portability vs ease-of-use (both for the client and the module maintainer).

What I found, in the end, was a particular flag in the [browserify](https://github.com/substack/node-browserify#usage) command line interface that can bundle the modules and expose them as global variables AND be used within RequireJS (if needed). Browserify (and others) call this Universal Module Definition (UMD). Some more about that [here](http://davidbcalhoun.com/2014/what-is-amd-commonjs-and-umd/).

By passing the `--standalone` flag in a browserify command, I can set my module up for UMD easily.

So...

Here's the `package.js` for **Module**:

```
{
  "name": "module",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "My module that requires another module (dependancy)",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "bundle": "browserify --standalone module index.js > module.js"
  },
  "author": "shennan",
  "devDependencies": {
    "dependancy": "*",
    "browserify": "*"
  }
}
```

So, when at the root of my module, I can run this in the command line:

```
$ npm run-script bundle
```

Which bundles up the dependancies into one file, and exposes them as per the UMD methodology. This means I can bootstrap the module in three different ways:

**NodeJS**

```
var Module = require('module');
/* use Module */
```

**Browser Vanilla**

```
<script src="module.js"></script>
<script>
  var Module = module;
  /* use Module */
</script>
```

**Browser with RequireJS**

```
<script src="require.js"></script>
<script>
  requirejs(['module.js'], function (Module) {
    /* use Module */
  });
</script>
```

Thanks again for everybody's input. All of the answers are valid and I encourage everyone to try them all as different use-cases will require different solutions.

Answer (score 1):

Of course you could use the same module **with** dependency on both sides. You just need to specify it better. This is the way I use:

```
(function (name, definition){
    if (typeof define === 'function'){ // AMD
        define(definition);
    } else if (typeof module !== 'undefined' && module.exports) { // Node.js
        module.exports = definition();
    } else { // Browser
        var theModule = definition(), global = this, old = global[name];
        theModule.noConflict = function () {
            global[name] = old;
            return theModule;
        };

        global[name] = theModule;
    }
})('Dependency', function () {
    // return the module's API
    return {
        'key': 'value'
    };
});
```

This is just a very basic sample - you can return function, instantiate function or do whatever you like. In my case I'm returning an object.

Now let's say this is the `Dependency` class. Your `Module` class should look pretty much the same, **but** it should have a dependency to `Dependency` like:

```
function (require, exports, module) {
    var dependency = require('Dependency');
}
```

In RequireJS this is called Simplified CommonJS Wrapper: http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#cjsmodule

Because there is a `require` statement at the beginning of your code, it will be matched as a dependency and therefore it will either be lazy loaded or if you optimize it - marked as a dependency early on (it will convert `define(definition)` to `define(['Dependency'], definition)` automatically).

The only problem here is to keep **the same** path to the files. Keep in mind that nested requires (if-else) won't work in Require (read the docs), so I had to do something like:

```
var dependency;
try {
    dependency = require('./Dependency'); // node module in the same folder
} catch(err) { // it's not node
    try {
        dependency = require('Dependency'); // requirejs
    } catch(err) { }
}
```

This worked perfectly for me. It's a bit tricky with all those paths, but at the end of the day, you get your two separate modules in different files which can be used on both ends **without** any kind of checks or hacks - they have all their dependencies are work like a charm :)

Comment: I see that [RequireJS](http://requirejs.org/) uses [AMD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asynchronous_module_definition). Would this not conflict server-side with Node's use of vanilla CommonJS? I'm not implying that it will, but in your experience do these two module systems play nice together if, for example, [Browserify](http://browserify.org/) was also used to package up the modules somewhere down the line?

Comment: If you trace the code you will see that it does all the checks so AMD modules are using `define` and node way of declaring uses `module.exports`. Therefore they just work out of the box nicely :) I'm very sorry I somehow decided you are already using `RequireJS` on client side because you try to make modules and that's what it does! My mistake here

Comment: It's said that browserify uses commonjs so it *should* be working straight out, hopefully :)

Comment: Yes, Browserify uses CommonJS, but RequireJS uses AMD which looks like CommonJS optimised for browsers. But I can see that they could potentially work together so long as Browserify was configured appropriately. It's not that I will be using Browserify, but others may use it to package the modules. I will give this a try this week and report back. Thanks.

Comment: https://github.com/substack/browserify-handbook#amd - as far as I can see, there won't be any difference between the two. Hope that works. Sorry for missing out the requirejs part :)

Comment: Hi, thanks again for this detailed answer. The problem I have with this is essentially that it requires the user of the module to include the RequireJS script in their document. That is an extra step, much like what I am trying to avoid in my question. This is still a valid option for bundling, but I was after something that was a little more out-of-the-box.

Comment: It should be working even without Require, as they are CommonJS wrappers :)

Comment: For the browser, it would need RequireJS.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [webpack](http://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html) bundler.
You can write module and export it via module exports. Then You can in server use that where you have module.export and for browser build with webpack. Configuration file usage would be the best option

```
module.exports = {
 entry: "./myModule",
 output: {
    path: "dist",
    filename: "myModule.js",
    library: "myModule",
    libraryTarget: "var"
 }
};
```

This will take myModule and export it to myModule.js file. Inside module will be assigned to var (libraryTarget flag) named myModule (library flag).

It can be exported as commonJS module, war, this, function

Since bundling is node script, this flag values can be grammatically set.

Take a look at externals flag. It is used if you want to have special behavior for some dependencies. For example you are creating react component and in your module you want to require it but not when you are bundling for web because it already is there.

Hope it is what you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. [Webpack](http://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html) looks like an interesting project. It looks like a good holistic approach to the common problem, though, dare I say, it does seem a little bit overkill for my particular use-case.